# Android: StatusLine now deprecated, what is the alternative?

Tags: android, deprecated

Google says that StatusLine now deprecated, according to this link: https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/22/changes/org.apache.http.StatusLine.html

I want a piece of code to know what is the status code for the server response, instead of the deprecated one.

What are the alternatives for it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `org.apache.http` package was deprecated for a while because of performance and other issues, and is now completely removed starting from API level 23.

You should use [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html), which has a nice documentation guiding you through the whole process.

If you need the status code, call [`getResponseCode()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getResponseCode%28%29) on the HttpURLConnection instance.

Here's a sample code:

```
@Nullable
public NetworkResponse openUrl(@NonNull String urlStr) {
    URL url = new URL(urlStr);
    // for secure connections, use this: HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    String networkErrorStr;

    try {
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

        InputStream er = connection.getErrorStream();

        if (er != null) {
            // if you get here, you'll anticipate an error, for example 404, 500, etc.
            networkErrorStr = getResponse(er); // save the error message
        }

        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream(); // this will throw an exception if the previous getErrorStream() wasn't null
        String responseStr = getResponse(is); // the actual response string on success

        return new NetworkResponse(responseCode, responseStr);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            if (connection != null) {
                // you have to call it again because the connection is now set to error mode
                int code = connection.getResponseCode();

                return new NetworkResponse(code, networkErrorStr); // response on error
            }
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace(); // for debug purposes
        }
        e.printStackTrace(); // for debug purposes
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }

    return null;
}

private String getResponse(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);

    String line;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        builder.append(line);
    }

    return builder.toString();
}

public static class NetworkResponse { // it is static because you will use it inside a class probably
    public NetworkResponse(int code, @Nullable String str) {
        // do whatever you want with the data
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I am using HttpURLConnection, but if i want to know the status code for server response, which code should i use? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `URL.openConnection()`. More details [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html#openConnection())

Comment: Yeah I am using HttpURLConnection, but if i want to know the status code for server response, which code should i use? thanks